# leaflet shiny palette issue

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

The variable I am trying to plot on a leaflet map is binary but I can't manage to have two distinct colors for each value (1 and 0). When the map loads, missing values are plotted in red, but the actual values are of the same color (something in between green and yellow). The 1 values should be green and 0 should be yellow. Here is the content of my `server.R`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  
  colorpalette1 <- c("#3EA055", "#C68E17")
  
  output$mymap1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(0, 28, 2)
  })
  
  selected <- reactive({
    data2 <- shape_data[[input$year]]
    data2
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$year, {
    bins1 <- c(1, 0)
    pal1 <- colorBin(colorpalette1, domain = selected(), bins = bins1, na.color = "#8C001A")
    
    leafletProxy("mymap1") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = shape_data,
                  fillColor = ~pal1(selected()),
                  weight = 1,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "black",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7
      )
  })
}
```

`input$year` is a `selectInput` that selects the variable to plot on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, `colorNumeric()` was more suitable than `colorBin()`.

```
pal1 <- colorNumeric(colorpalette1, domain = shape_data[[input$year]], na.color = "#8C001A")
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to provide a minimally reproducible example, so that we can verify the issue and test the solution. You can try the following:

```
observeEvent(input$year, {
  if (!is.null(input$year)){
    bins1 <- c(1, 0)
    pal1 <- colorBin(colorpalette1, domain = selected(), bins = bins1, na.color = "#8C001A")
    
    leafletProxy("mymap1") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = shape_data,
                  fillColor = ~pal1(selected()),
                  weight = 1,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "black",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7
      )
  }else{return(NULL)}
})
```